# Automator workflow to screen capture a series of video links

Tags: applescript, automator, screen-capture

My job requires me to screen capture recordings in Adobe Connect, using Camtasia. I would love to set up a list of urls for many of these recordings and have Automator cruise through them while I'm away from the machine. The workflow would start with a list of urls. For each one it would:

- Click on the url to launch Adobe Connect
- Start Camtasia recording the
  screen for 70 minutes
- Maximize the Adobe Connect window
- Stop and save
  the recording (ideally with a custom name connected to the original
  url, but I can do without that)
- Close the Adobe Connect window and close the Camtasia recording
- Repeat
  for all the urls on the list

I've barely used Automator but [I actually managed to get it partially working](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dc9tzt5y9nwrdlr/AABQCCPnRPnJ9qR-qvDOtbf6a?dl=0). The thing I don't know how to do is have it repeat using a list of urls. My workflow just gets it to do all the steps once, which doesn't really save me any time. I also need some kind of variable in the Apple Script that makes Camtasia vary the name it uses to save the file. Otherwise Camtasia is going to save over the same filename again and again.

EDIT:
I managed to almost get it done (maybe?) with this Applescript.

```
set myList to {"p10nlnl2mk6x", "pdweybcght9w", "pq7aydrk6712", "pc8vtqhtvk13", "pooix1p6mpk3", "p0xlc3nttd2m", "p7q09gm8dbhd", "pvccnetb4z1s", "pz0b03x0nauz", "pw4lr56emb8a", "pg6kxxzlo5mv", "pn97lly62vi0"}
repeat with theItem in myList
    open location "https://example.com/" & theItem
    delay 10
    tell application "System Events"
        perform action "AXPress" of (first button whose subrole is "AXFullScreenButton") of (first window whose subrole is "AXStandardWindow") of (first process whose frontmost is true)
    end tell
    tell application "Camtasia 3"
        startRecording region {0, 0, 2880, 1800}
        delay 4200
        stopRecording
        save document 1 in "/Users/[user]/Desktop/" & theItem
        close theItem
    end tell
    tell application "Adobe Connect"
        quit
    end tell
end repeat
```

But it fails on the "save document 1" line. I get:

```
error "Camtasia 3 got an error: Can’t get document 1. Invalid index." number -1719 from document 1
```

EDIT 2:

Okay I have a solution that I think works but isn't the most elegant. It requires Camtasia to already be open, and then uses keyboard shortcuts to start and stop the recording.

```
repeat with theItem in myList
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 19 using {command down, shift down}
        delay 2
        click checkbox "Start Recording" of window "Camtasia Recorder" of application process "Camtasia 3"
    end tell
    open location "https://liveonline.kaptest.com/" & theItem
    delay 20
    tell application "System Events"
        perform action "AXPress" of (first button whose subrole is "AXFullScreenButton") of (first window whose subrole is "AXStandardWindow") of (first process whose frontmost is true)
    end tell
    delay 4500
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 19 using {command down, option down}
        delay 5
    end tell
    tell application "Adobe Connect"
        quit
    end tell
end repeat
```

This results in all the recordings being collected in a single Untitled Camtasia document, but that's fine because the raw recordings are in a temp folder somewhere I can get at after this is done. It accomplishes my main goal, which is to walk away from the machine overnight and have it offline individual recordings unattended.

Comment: Are you looking for a complete solution, or just wondering how to do a loop in AppleScript? There are tons of resources that explain repeat loops that you can get from a quick google search. You just need to repeat through the list of URL's in order to name each video. I think your question would be cleaner and clearer if you had an actual request, as opposed to a somewhat open ended question.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! You show only one **URL** in the **Get Specified URLs** _action_ in the linked **Automator** _workflow_, yet you say you "would love to set up a list of urls", so it's not clear if each **URL** is to be recorded for 70 minutes or what. Would you please clarify that.

Comment: That's correct. Each url is a recording of about 60 minutes. I was going to have it record for 70 minutes to make sure I get the whole thing. I can trim down these Camtasia files later, I just want to capture a bunch overnight.

Comment: @ChrisNorman, where I'm really stumped is this piece of Apple Script which I copied from a Camtasia support page:

tell application "Camtasia 3"
 startRecording region {0, 0, 2880, 1800}
 delay 4200
 stopRecording
        save document 1 in "/Users/username/Desktop/myProject"
end tell

In order to have this work for MULTIPLE docs, doesn't the script need to vary the name of the file I'm saving as? If there's a piece of Apple Script that would add a timestamp that would make the file name unique, for instance.

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running? (Need to know so I test under the same version, if possible.)

Comment: @user3439894.  10.14.6 Mojave

Comment: With having a 70 minute delay and especially wanting to do many **URLs** I would not use **Automator** as IMO it's not really designed to run such long automations. I'd actually write it completely in **AppleScript** in two **AppleScript** _scripts_, or as apps, or trigged by `osascript` setup to run as either a **Launch Agent** or scheduled through **Calendar**. First one starts the process and terminates and the second one runs 70 minutes later, saves the recording etc, and terminates. This way you don't have a **AppleScript** or **Automator** _process_ waiting for a 70 minute delay.

Comment: That said, you only need one **Run Apple Script** _action_, for the current _code_, not two, and you can just use the _set_ of _actions_ and replicate the _set_ with a break between them. In other words, under **Options** for an _action_, the **[√] Ignore this action's input** would be checked to unlink it from the previous set of _actions_. You'd just have to put a different **URL** in each **Get Specified URLs** _action_. The name to save the _file_ to can be _coded_ to create unique names.

Comment: Never written Apple Script before, which is why I was leaning on Automator. Maybe I can record most of it and then work from there? But I doubt I'm gonna be able to have Apple Script pull data from a list or csv without a similar template to start with -- that seems advanced. I'll give it a try. Thanks for the guidance.